# Easy linear algebra question; why does this hold?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\Sigma$ be a covariance matrix and $\Sigma_{R_p,R}$ a covariance vector.

Assume $$W = \Sigma^{-1} (\Sigma_{R_p,R} - \lambda \cdot \boldsymbol{1}) \\  W^T \boldsymbol{1} = 1$$

Want to solve for $\lambda$. $\Sigma$ is symetric, so $ W^T = \Sigma^{-1} (\Sigma_{R_p,R} - \lambda \cdot \boldsymbol{1})^T$. Then $W^T \boldsymbol{1} = \Sigma^{-1} (\Sigma_{R_p,R} - \lambda \cdot \boldsymbol{1})^T \boldsymbol{1}$.

However, in prof notes, it reads  $W^T \boldsymbol{1} = \boldsymbol{1}^T \Sigma^{-1} (\Sigma_{R_p,R} - \lambda \cdot \boldsymbol{1})$.

Is this equivalent?

Comment: For any two vectors, $x, y$ and a symmetric matrix $A$, $x^{\top} A y = (x^{\top} A y)^{\top} = y^{\top} A^{\top} x = y^{\top} A x$.